# Get Auth Token to see public posts

Tags: authentication, facebook-access-token

I'm building an application that is like an RSS reader for public pages feeds. My problem is I don't want the user to have to login (since I have no care who they are), yet to access public feeds Facebook requires that an app have a access_token. I was wondering if there is a way to get a token "for the app" that allows me to see public feeds.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/

Comment: I tried that but the access token that gives me cannot see the public pages

Comment: Then they're not public pages, they must have some sort of geographic or age-based restriction

Comment: (if `https://graph.facebook.com/<PAGE ID>` returns 'false', this is the case)

Comment: I can access the pages base information, but if I try to get the posts (`https://graph.facebook.com/<PAGE ID>/posts`) without an access token I get an error from Facebook.

Comment: What error are you getting? Does it work with a user access token? you could just use your own access token or that of a test user

Comment: I get a 400 return saying I need an access token. Yes I can use my own token (which I have been for testing) but I obviously don't want it to use my token for other users.

Comment: The app isn't set to 'native/desktop' mode is it? if so, using the app access token is the same as not using any token

Comment: Write that as an answer, you hit the problem right on the nail!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to access any publicly accessible page using the app access token.

If this isn't working, check that your app is not set to 'Native/Desktop' mode in the app settings, if it is, the app access token isn't trusted, because it's assumed your native app is distributed with the app secret in the binary. In this case, you'll see error messages implying there's no access token even when there is, etc.